# Dynamically update list element height in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I have a list. 
When you click on element, it becomes selected, and should be expanded vertically to displat some more data.

I am trying to accomplish this by adding to each element's layout "Details" view which is hidden by dafault and is set to VISIBLE onClick.

The only problem that the height of element isn't changed. 
If I try to it like this:

```
                    holder.line_view
                        .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, dip(
                                        convertView.getContext(), 30)));
```

then I get unknown exception.
Just

```
holder.details_pane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

doesn't work, the size isn't changed.

**Please advise.**

---

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/line_view">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Description" />
<TextView
    android:text="LALALA"
    android:id="@+id/detailed_desc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

In adapter I try:

```
 @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
case TYPE_ITEM_EXPANDED:
                    holder.details_pane.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
...
case TYPE_ITEM_NORMAL:
                    holder.details_pane.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "doesn't work, the size isn't changed"

something to try if you allow your view to be rotated: make your view redraw itself and see if the row is bigger.

It might be that you just need to invalidate the listview so that it redraws. Possibly invalidate the row.

maybe it's even as easy as calling notifyDataSetChanged(); on your custom listview adapter

Comment: Right, all was needed to be done - is calling notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the issue of you code. but you should try this

```
com.android.widget.ExpandableListView
com.android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter
```

this is designed for your requirement and shipped with the OS

Comment: thanks but i need to have hierarchy of arbitary depth - ExpandableView has only 2 levels.